# Updating windows server remotely via Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server, winrm

Hello I have been trying to make this script work for some time now, but I keep running into problems. The script is written with multiple servers in mind, although I am just testing it only on one test system for now.

Following I will post the script.

```
#List of Servers
$SQLServer = @('testserver.net')
$ApplicationServer = @('testserver.net')
$Servers = @($SQLServer, $ApplicationServer)
$ServiceName = @('tomcat9', 'MSSQLSERVER')

#Information Message
Write-Host "Starting update process for the following Servers:" $Servers "and Services:" $ServiceName

#Gets status of Servers
ForEach ($Index in $Servers)
{
    Invoke-command {Get-Service tomcat9} -comp $Servers[$Index]
    Invoke-command {Get-Service -Name 'MSSQLSERVER'} -comp $Servers[$Index]
}

#Information Message
Write-Host "Stopping the specified Services:" $ServiceName

#Stops services
#Sequentially stops TomCat and then DB Applications
ForEach ($Index in $Servers)
{
    $ArrayService = Invoke-Command {Get-Service tomcat9} -comp $Servers[$Index]
    if ($ArrayService.Status -ne "Stopped")
    {
    Invoke-Command {Stop-Service tomcat9} -comp $Servers[$Index]
    }

    $ArrayService = Invoke-Command {Get-Service -Name 'MSSQLSERVER'} -comp $Servers[$Index]
    if ($ArrayService.Status -ne "Stopped")
    {
    Invoke-Command {Stop-Service -Name 'MSSQLSERVER'} -comp $Servers[$Index]
    }
}

#Information Message
Write-Host "Will now start Windows Updates on servers and reboot"

#Will Update Windows, automatically reboot and out the log in the specified directory. This will be done to all listed Servers
ForEach ($Index in $Servers)
{
    $Scriptblock = {
        Invoke-WUJob -Comp $Servers[$Index] -RunNow -Confirm:$false -Verbose -Script {
            Install-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate -NotCategory "SilverLight" -NotTitle "Preview" -AcceptAll -AutoReboot | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log
            }
        }
    Invoke-Command -Comp $Servers[$Index] -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock
}

#Information Message
Write-Host "Starting up Services again"

#Starting SQL Server and checking if its running, if not running it will give more time before the Script continues
ForEach ($Index in $SQLServer)
{
    $ArrayService = Invoke-Command {Get-Service -Name $ServiceName} -comp $SQLServer[$Index]

    $FilteredService = $ArrayService | where {$_ -like 'MSQL'}
    while ($FilteredService.Status -ne 'Running')
    {
        Invoke-Command {Start-Service $FilteredService} -comp $SQLServer[$Index]
        Write-Host $FilteredService.Status
        Write-Host "SQL Service starting on " $SQLServer[$Index] 
        function Check-Status 
        {
            Start-Sleep -seconds 30
            $FilteredService.Refresh()
            if ($FilteredService.Status -eq 'Running')
            {
                Write-Host "SQL Service running"
                #Invoke-Command {Start-Service $ArrayService | where {$_ -like 'tomcat9'}} -comp $ApplicationServer
            }
            else
            {
                Check-Status
            }
        }
    }
}

#Starting TomCat Service again
ForEach ($Index in $ApplicationServer)
{
    Write-Host "MUMService starting on " $ApplicationServer[$Index]
    #Invoke-Command {Start-Service $ArrayService | where {$_ -like 'tomcat9'}} -comp $ApplicationServer[$Index]
    $ServiceStatus = Invoke-Command {Get-Service tomcat9} -comp $ApplicationServer[$Index]
    if ($ServiceStatus.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Invoke-Command {Start-Service $ArrayService | where {$_ -like 'tomcat9'}} -comp $ApplicationServer[$Index]
        Write-Host "MUM Service running"
    }
    else 
    {
        Invoke-Command {Start-Service $ArrayService | where {$_ -like 'tomcat9'}} -comp $ApplicationServer[$Index]
    }
}


ForEach ($Index in $Servers)
{
    invoke-command {Get-Service mum_software_tomcat9} -comp $Servers[$Index]
    invoke-command {Get-Service -Name 'MSSQLSERVER'} -comp $Servers[$Index]
}
```

Either my logic is really wrong, or this doesnt work this way in powershell, but when I try to execute the script as is, there is an error for the parameter 'ComputerName'. It says that the argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again. Apparently it does not like $SQLServer[$Index].

The update functionality itself seems to work by itself though.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: In `ForEach ($Index in $Servers)`, `$Index` is assigned the value of the next server name in the array each time around, so `-comp $Servers[$Index]` should simply be `-comp $Index`.  Incidentally the `-ComputerName` parameter accepts an array of names, so you could get rid of the explicit loops and just use `-comp $Servers`.  You can also remove some of the calls to `Invoke-Command` by combining the scriptblocks instead of making one call to check something then another to change it.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Will test this out in a bit and reedit if it works accordingly. So you mean when I write  `-comp $Index` I can just get rid of my `ForEach` loops?

Comment: No, `$Index` won't exist when the loops are gone. So, either keep the loops and use `$Index` or get rid of them and just pass `$Servers` to `Invoke-Command` and it will execute the command against each one.  Check out the [Invoke-Command help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1) for details.

Comment: Got it! Everything seems to work good now till the `Write-Host "Starting up services again"`. Here it tells me now that it "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'InputObject'. The argument is null or empty..." I suppose its because some variable is not declared, but as far as I can see everything is declared fine..?